# What is needed for basic PIC programming?

Tags: pic, programmer

I have a bunch of PICs that have been sitting in the basement for a year, and I really want to learn how to program and put them to use.

I have some 16C57's, 16C73, 16C71, 16C54, 16C74, 16C55, and 16C505. Some are write only, but a few from each category are erasable.

I want to do basic I/O with LED output and digital voltage sources.

What are the basic components I need, and where can I find instructions on programming them assuming I am a beginner programmer.

For example, if I acquire a USB programmer, do I also need a crystal, capacitors etc. for a basic setup?

Comment: For the crystals,caps and other components you call check the datasheet of you device to see how to use it and program it.

Comment: This question is too broad for the SE format. Could you try asking a more specific question (maybe only the last one)? Also, did you search for things like 'PIC tutorial', 'PIC circuit diagram', etc? There's a lot of resources out there.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that you lose your PICs in the basement. They are "C" devices and do not have Flash. This means that they may be erasable by UV (Quartz Window) or totally non-erasable OTP devices.

You should start with some new generation PIC microcontrollers which require less elaborate setup than the older series.

Here is a [PIC tutorial](http://blog.irwellsprings.com/getting-started-with-pic-microcontrollers/) to get you started.

To program new generation PIC you would minimally need:

1. [MPLABX](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/) environment setup on a machine (Windows or Linux)
   [image: MPLABX]
2. A [PICKIT3](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=PG164130&utm_source=&utm_medium=MicroSolutions&utm_term=&utm_content=&utm_campaign=PICkit%203) to program and debug your PIC
   [image: PICKIT3]
3. A Breadboard to experiment
   [image: Breadboard]
4. A basic 5V or  3.3V power supply
   [image: Power Supply]

You may not need crystals and caps as most of the ne generation PICs come with an internal oscillator.

Comment: *"You may not need crystals and caps"* - except maybe for decoupling.

Comment: For the newer generation PICS, I do not need Xtals. What about when I get to the older ones like the ones I have